# VSCode muda a indentação quando salvo o projeto

Tags: visual-studio-code

Eu já setei a indentação no `User settings` para 2 espaços e ele até funciona quando eu aperto no tab, mas sempre que eu salvo o arquivo ele automaticamente muda toda a indentação para 4 espaços. Dei uma olhada em todas as preferências e não encontrei nada referente a uma auto-indentação ou coisa do tipo.

Comment: Qual o tipo do arquivo que você está trabalhando?

Comment: @gmsantos é .html